# Auditing the nodes in Adobe CQ 561

Tags: adobe, aem

I want to get the list of changes on a particular node in CQ 561.
Also I need the previous valued and the modified values in the changes list.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no way to get that functionality without coding.
You can observe the JCR node(s) and its properties using **javax.jcr.observation.ObservationManager**
Create a JCR **EventListener** and register it in ObservationManager which can be retreived from JCR session. See [example](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/events.html#main-pars_text_12) for more details.
But **javax.jcr.observation.Event** does not contain the previous value(s) so you have to organize this logic yourself.

```
package com.adobe.aem.events;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.jcr.Repository;
import javax.jcr.RepositoryException;
import javax.jcr.Session;
import javax.jcr.observation.Event;
import javax.jcr.observation.EventIterator;
import javax.jcr.observation.EventListener;
import javax.jcr.observation.ObservationManager;
import org.apache.sling.jcr.api.SlingRepository;
import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Activate;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;

import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolverFactory ; 
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver; 
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource; 

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Just a simple DS Component
 */
@Component(metatype=true)
@Service
public class SimpleDSComponent implements Runnable,EventListener {

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private BundleContext bundleContext;

    //Inject a Sling ResourceResolverFactory
    @Reference
    private ResourceResolverFactory resolverFactory;

    private Session session;

    private ObservationManager observationManager;

    //Inject a Sling ResourceResolverFactory to create a Session requited by the EventHandler
    @Reference
    private SlingRepository repository;

    public void run() {
        log.info("Running...");
    }


    //Place app logic here to define the AEM Custom Event Handler
    protected void activate(ComponentContext ctx) {
        this.bundleContext = ctx.getBundleContext();
        try
        {

            //Invoke the adaptTo method to create a Session 
             ResourceResolver resourceResolver = resolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
             session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);

            // Setup the event handler to respond to a new claim under content/claim.... 
                observationManager = session.getWorkspace().getObservationManager();
                 final String[] types = { "nt:unstructured","sling:Folder" };
                 final String path = "/content/claim"; // define the path
                 observationManager.addEventListener(this, Event.NODE_ADDED, path, true, null, types, false);
                 log.info("Observing property changes to {} nodes under {}", Arrays.asList(types), path);

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }

    protected void deactivate(ComponentContext componentContext) throws RepositoryException {
        if(observationManager != null) {
            observationManager.removeEventListener(this);
        }
        if (session != null) {
            session.logout();
            session = null;
        }
    }

    //Define app logic that is fired when the event occurs - simply track the time 
    //when the event occurred. 
    public void onEvent(EventIterator itr) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        //log the time when the event occurred 
        log.info("A new node was added to content/claim at : " +cal.getTime());         
    }
}
```

Also see [Javadoc](http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-1.0/javax/jcr/observation/EventListener.html):

> An EventListener can be registered via the ObservationManager object. Event listeners are notified asynchronously, and see events after they occur and the transaction is committed. An event listener only sees events for which the session that registered it has sufficient access rights.